# Sorting Issue After Table Render in Laravel DataTables as a Service Implementation

Tags: laravel, datatables, eloquent

I have implemented laravel dataTable as a service.
The initial two columns are actual id and names so, I am able to sort it asc/desc after the table renders.
But the next few columns renders after performing few calculations, i.e. these values are not fetched directly from any column rather it is processed.
I am unable to sort these columns where calculations were performed, and I get this error. And I know it is looking for that particular column for eg outstanding_amount which I don't have in the DB, rather it is a calculated amount from two or more columns that are in some other tables.
Any Suggestions on how to overcome this issue?

[image: After clicking the Outstanding column]

Comment: Can you include the query you are using to get your data? This will help to give some directions on changing it.

Comment: The below link has the code i posted on the GitHub page https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/issues/1790

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to sort by values that aren't columns, but calculated values. 
So the main issue here is to give Eloquent/MySql the data it needs to provide the sorting.

```php
// You might need to do some joins first
->addSelect(DB::raw('your_calc as outstanding_amount'))
->orderBy('outstanding_amount') // asc can be omitted as this is the default

// Anternative: you don't need the value sorted by
// Don't forget any joins you might need
->orderByRaw('your_calc_for_outstanding_amount ASC')
```

Comment: Well, all my calculations are done in the editColumn and not in the query() function. So are you suggesting me to write the logic in the query() function itself?

Comment: After looking at your code, the editColumn function makes data available for Datatables, bu MySql doesn't know about it - so it can't be used for sorting. You'd need to order by a raw SQL statement (so the second option in my answer) Good luck!

Comment: Sure, i will give it a try.

Comment: The ->addSelect() works perfectly to ordering each calculated columns. Thanks. The only doubt I have now is, if u see my code, the last column is the outstanding amount, which is neither a column nor any calculation logic occurs. It just adds up the previously calculated column values.  Now how should I accommodate the code for outstanding in the addSelect()? Do I have to write the raw queries for all the above addSelect into the last addSelect?

Comment: Not too sure about it, but I think you'll have to. I'd give it a try first using the previously calculated values to calculate oustanding_amount, otherwise you'll have to do a raw count for it.

Answer (score 0):

For SQL functions it'll work as follow

```
->addSelect(DB::raw('COUNT(products.id) as product_count'));
->orderByRaw(DB::raw('COUNT(products.id)'),'DESC');
```